# Port definition per Webservices at Glassfish 3.1

Tags: glassfish-3

I have a war file contains two webservices helloService and Calculator.
Is it possible to establish these services at different port? For instance

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloService
http://localhost:8085/CalculatorService
```

I am using glassfish 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is nor possible, because a war file corresponds a component on which all service establihed same listener.